# Многопоточность в Python - зло?

Tags: python, многопоточность

У меня есть многофункциональная программа, которая сильно зависит от времени. Она выполняет разные действия с разными промежутками времени. Для этого я использовал потоки. Например один поток считывает нажатия клавиш клавиатуры каждые 10мс, второй флудит в консоль каждые 10 секунд, третий распознает код на картинке каждую минуту и т.д. Надеюсь вы поняли о чем я.
Потоков в сумме где-то 4-6. В общем сидел я на этих потоках, все отлично работает, ошибок и коллизий не выдает - шикарно.

Внезапно где-то вычитал, что потоки в Питоне - не совсем хорошая вещь, что потоков всего можно создать столько, сколько ядер в процессоре, что потоки жрут много памяти, если внутри них бесконечный цикл (контролируемый) и т.д.

Теперь страшно - как реализовать такую задачу (выполнение разных действий через разные промежутки времени) без потоков? Или стоит оставить потоки? А если потоков будет 10? 15? 100?

Заранее спасибо за все ответы и советы :)

Comment: Нет, всё не *настолько* плохо. Не надо плодить сотни потоков, и всё будет хорошо. А если вам понадобилась сотня потоков, то скорее всего вы что-то делаете не так

Comment: Все нормально с потоками, ну и да делать их сильно больше чем ядер процессора не есть хорошо. Можно еще в асинхронность поиграть но там тоже свои замарочки.

Comment: Ну у каждого компуктера разное количество ядер. А если их два, а потоков 3? Ну и в таком духе. К чему это приведет?

Comment: Зависит от программы насколько она загружает систему. Такое небольшое превышение проблем обычно не создает. А вот 100 потоков это уже проблема...

Comment: @CSharpLooser если потоки не грузят систему непрерывно, то ничего страшного не произойдёт. В системе и без вас крутятся сотни других потоков от чужих программ, и ничего, всё работает

Comment: Потоки как в жизни в меру все хорошо. Переедать вредно недоедать тоже. Так сколько есть? - в меру. А она у всех разная. Вот вам и пространство для маневра и работы

Comment: А по мне так потоки в питоне вообще вещь фактически бесполезная с точки зрения попытки распределения нагрузки на ядра. Из за GIL у вас все равно одновременно работает только один поток исполняющий python код. Фактически разработчики питона сделали потоки для работы в случаях когда надо ожидать ввода-вывода, что более правильно решать асинхронностью. А если надо паралелить вычислительные задачи (то для чего в других языках как раз используются потоки), придется использовать уже мультипроцессы.

Comment: И да, потоки не настолько тяжелы как процессы, но все равно гораздо тяжелее чем корутины. Так что как по мне лучше использовать asyncio везде, где только возможно

Comment: а я вот не понял почему кол-во потоков должно зависеть от кол-ва ядер? хотя бы потому что, как сказали выше, "в системе и так уже крутится сотни потоков" - это раз, а пайтон так вообще на одном ядре завязан. мы же не о мультипроцессинге говорим. - это два.